# Brother MFC 9450: printer report emty toner cartridge - but it is not empty

Tags: laser-printer, toner

Brother MFC 9450: printer report emty toner cartridge - but it is not empty
How can I reset the toner catridge "TN-135?

Answer (score 0):

If the printers are sufficiently similar, perhaps [these](https://superuser.com/questions/1363385/brother-dcp-1510-how-to-reset-toner-cartridge/1363390#1363390) instructions can help you.

Comment: Please include the relevant information in your answer- even if you're linking to another answer on Super User (and remember to give attribution!) :)