# Brother DCP-1510: How to reset toner cartridge

Tags: laser-printer, brother-printer, toner, cartridge

My printer (Type: Brother DCP-1510) reports that the toner is empty and refuses to print. However, the last pages printed were perfect. How can I convince it that everything's all right?

Answer (score 2):

I just managed to fix it. The issue is the 'Replace Toner' message appeared on the screen and won't allow any prints. Below is the solution:

1. Press Menu button: Options will appear, press ok for the option 1. General Setup
2. Go down by the arrow key to option 4. Replace Toner and Press OK
3. Use Arrow Key UP or Down and you will see option (Replace Toner Continue) and press OK.
   Do not select option (Replace Toner Stop).

This will fix the issue and you can print with the low toner until you get a replacement toner sorted.

Trust this helps.

Asim Hashmi
Lancashire, UK

Answer (score 0):

I found good instructions [here](https://www.khl-inkt.be/inkt/blog/brother-dcp-1510-en-dcp-1512-reset/) (in Dutch):

1. Press the **menu**-button,
2. Use the arrows to browse to "machine info", press **OK**,
3. Use the arrows to browse to "reset drum",
4. Press and hold **OK** until the display shows

> **^**  reset
>
> **v**  empty

5. Instead of using any of these options, press **Start**,
6. Immediately after that, repeatedly press the arrow up (**^**) until the display shows the number 10,
7. Immediately after that, press **OK**; the display should say "Accepted",
8. Press **Stop** to exit the menu.
9. To be sure, switch the printer off and on.

After step 4, you may instead get the message "Printer is busy". Switching the printer off and on worked for me.

Steps 5-7 may also fail, I suspect that this happens when you are too slow.